How to define deployment mode as Simple Scalable Deployment in loki-stack chart?
I want to deploy loki via helm using grafana/loki-stack helm chart. But I want to use deploymentMode as SimpleScalable i.e., SSD. I tried adding deploymentMode in values, but it doesn't work. Does loki-stack even support SSD deployment mode? From the documentation, this is community maintained chart and not recommended by grafana team. So does that mean this chart do not have SSD/distributed deployment modes?

The chart  grafana/loki support simple scalable mode, and It is the default deployment mode in the latest version. In addition, You can use the chart grafana/loki-simple-scalable instead.

I believe latest version is 2.10.2, I am already on 2.10.1 and by default its installing binary Loki and not simple scalable. I am referring to https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.   @yungkei
Let me know if my understanding is wrong?

Sorry, I checked the repository. As you say, the chart loki-stack is not a simple scalable mode. In the old version, you could use the chart grafana/loki-simple-scalable,  but now you can use grafana/loki. Aslo, you can refer to https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/setup/install/helm/install-scalable/
